# Failed to load resource : the server responded with a status 404 error

Tags: apex, community

When trying to run a community I am getting the following error :

Failed to load resource : the server responded with a status 404 error.[image]

What can be the possible reason and how to resolve as sometime on reload it works fine.

Comment: You can check trust site for any performance degradation on Salesforce end. You can also try to delete the static resource and upload it again.

Comment: seems like your jquery file is not loaded properly...

Comment: can you show your code for loading the static resource?  Are you using Visualforce?  Lightning Component?

Comment: There is nothing different it works fine for mozilla and IE but fails for chrome